# How to swap two row vectors inside a row vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, swap

i am trying to swap 2 row vectors which are inside a row vector.

For example:

```
a=[1 2 3];
b=[5 3];
c=[9 3 7 6];
d=[7 5];

X1= [ a, b , d, c ];
```

I want to do random swapping such that two of the  a,b,c,d remains at the same position in X1 and the remaining two of them shuffles in X1. For example, some of the possible random swaps are: 
`[b,a,d,c] % a and b swap with each other whereas d and c remain at the same place`

`[d,b,a,c] % a and d swap with each other whereas b and c remain at the same place`

`[c,b,d,a] % a and c swap with each other whereas b and d remain at the same place`
.....
.....

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking

Answer (score 4):

The proper and safe way to what you're trying to do is by assigning your variables to a `cell`, permuting the elements of the cell, and finally concatenating the result.

Imagine a specific permutation, say, `[c, b, a, d]`. This permutation can be coded as `[3, 2, 1, 4]` in terms of a mapping. The corresponding code to generate your array is then:

```
% generate input
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [5, 3];
c = [9, 3, 7, 6];
d = [7, 5];

% generate cell to permute
tmpcell = {a, b, c, d};

% define our permutation
permnow = [3, 2, 1, 4];

% permute and concatenate the result into an array
result = [tmpcell{permnow}];

% check if this is indeed OK:
disp(isequal(result,[c, b, a, d]))  % should print 1
```

The only thing you might still need is to generate a random configuration. This is easy: you just have to choose 2 random indices and swap them in `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. A lazy option to do this:

```
nvars = length(tmpcell);         % generalizes to multiple variables this way
idperm = 1:nvars;
i1 = randi(nvars,1);
partperm = setdiff(idperm, i1);  % vector of remaining indices, avoid duplication
i2 = partperm(randi(nvars-1,1)); % second index, guaranteed distinct from i1
permnow = idperm;
permnow([i1, i2]) = [i2, i1];    % swap the two indices
```

Comment: I could not agree more. I get the impression is that this is not what the OP is requesting, but it is the best guess with the fairly limited information provided. Anyway +1.